# How to restrict a jquery find with selectors?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I want to restrict what gets returned from the following code. I have this, which returns all parents which are ul's. i.e. basically all UL's in my tree, but what I want is just the UL's in the current branch. 
The branch in question is the one ticked green in the image.
So, not the other main branches under the root (Admin). (eg not the branches for  Contacts, Security etc. )

[image: Tree image]

i.e. Admin -> Users -> new subby tst3 -> Read

How would I do that?

```
var parentEls = $(this).parents("ul").find("input[type=checkbox]")
```

the markup is

```html
<li>
 <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#MMID_0">
  <span class="checkbox MMTree-checkbox styled red"><input name="MM_0" class="MMTree-checkbox styled red" id="MM_0" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="0"></span>
  Admin
 </span>
 <ul class="nav nav-list collapse in" id="MMID_0" aria-expanded="true" style="padding-left: 20px;">
  <li>
   <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu_0_0">
    <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_0_0" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_0_0" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
    Debtors-Creditors
   </span>
   <ul class="nav nav-list collapse" id="submenu_0_0" aria-expanded="true" style="padding-left: 20px;">
    <li>
     <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu_0_0SM_0_00">
      <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="Pr_SM_0_00" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="Pr_SM_0_00" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="0"></span>
      Read
     </span>
    </li>
    <li>
     <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu_0_0SM_0_10">
      <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="Pr_SM_0_10" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="Pr_SM_0_10" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="0"></span>
      Create
     </span>
    </li>
    <li>
     <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu_0_0SM_0_20">
      <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="Pr_SM_0_20" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="Pr_SM_0_20" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="0"></span>
      Update
     </span>
    </li>
    <li>
     <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu_0_0SM_0_30">
      <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="Pr_SM_0_30" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="Pr_SM_0_30" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="0"></span>
      Delete
     </span>
    </li>
   </ul>

  </li>
  <li>
   <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Smenu_0_1__1">
    <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_0_1" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_0_1" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
    Users
   </span>
   <ul class="nav nav-list collapse in" id="Smenu_0_1__1" aria-expanded="true" style="padding-left: 60px;">
    <li>
     <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Smenu_0_1__10">
      <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_0_1_1" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_0_1_1" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="2"></span>
      new subby tst3
     </span>
     <ul class="nav nav-list collapse in" id="Smenu_0_1__10" aria-expanded="true" style="padding-left: 20px;">
      <li>
       <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Smenu_0_1__10SM_0_1_1_00">
        <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled green checked"><input name="Pr_SM_0_1_1_00" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="Pr_SM_0_1_1_00" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="0"></span>
        Read
       </span>
      </li>
      <li>
       <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Smenu_0_1__10SM_0_1_1_10">
        <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="Pr_SM_0_1_1_10" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="Pr_SM_0_1_1_10" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="0"></span>
        Create
       </span>
      </li>
      <li>
       <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Smenu_0_1__10SM_0_1_1_20">
        <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="Pr_SM_0_1_1_20" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="Pr_SM_0_1_1_20" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="0"></span>
        Update
       </span>
      </li>
      <li>
       <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Smenu_0_1__10SM_0_1_1_30">
        <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="Pr_SM_0_1_1_30" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="Pr_SM_0_1_1_30" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="0"></span>
        Delete
       </span>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>

  </li>
  <li>
   <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Smenu_0_1__2">
    <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_0_2" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_0_2" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
    Contacts
   </span>
   <ul class="nav nav-list collapse" id="Smenu_0_1__2" style="padding-left: 60px;">
    <li>
```

Comment: Do you want Users-> new subby tst3 as output or just  new subby tst3.

Comment: find("input[type=checkbox]") does not indicate selected checkbox. It just indicates any checkbox. you may want to add selector for determining selected checkbox

Comment: I would like up to and including Users. I tried parentsUntil.
Each parent has a unique id which forms part of each child,..so I'm hoping there a way of doing it with the first couple of letters and numbers which make up the Key,..eg The first branch would be SM_0_0, and it's children would be SM_0_0_0, SM_0_0_0_ , SM_0_0_1_ etc

Comment: As background, I'm iterating up from the clicked on checkbox, in order to get parents and siblings going up in order to set the tri-state checkboxes at parent levels (i.e. all green checked or grey checked or red unchecked).

Comment: may be it will be good idea to write intent in question itself. And for solving same, you may check for all ul, if they have child containing red and green checked mark it grey all green mark it green and so on. I am just suggesting that by getting all ul under Admin and then using top down approach will be less hard coded solution to your problem

Comment: Thx. Yes I guess that is the only alternative I have.
I had hoped there was something like
$(this).parents("ul").find("input[type=checkbox]").where(attr("id") == varSomeIdpart;

Comment: while you may find such a method but hard coding is not good practice. also its not extendable